# mod_rewrite rewrite all but index.php

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

In my htaccess i have

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ cms.php?seotitle=$1 [L]`

The idea is that index.html will load fine and then anything requested at domain.com/anythinghere.html will use the rule of grabbing the file from cms.php.

However its not working - any clues? Really need this sorted asap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(cms\.php|index\.html)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ cms.php?seotitle=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(index.html)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ cms.php?seotitle=$1 [L]
```

Another way is to use the `-f` or `-d` flags, which mean existing file or directory.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ cms.php?seotitle=$1 [L]
```

When you use this, any existing file or directory will not be rewritten. This is useful, especially for css or js files.

Comment: It doesnt work still. It loads my page template but will not load the content. if i type in the browser mydomain.com/cms.php?seotitle=something.html then it works fine but the rewrite still doesnt work.

Comment: Should it be index.php instead of .html? The key part is the RewriteCond.

If that still doesn't work, change the rewriterule to something like test.php that just does print_R($_GET)

Comment: I did as you said with test.php and got the following when trying to request mydomain.com/about.html
<code>
Array ( [seotitle] => test.php )
</code>

Comment: that new code with the flags prevents even the index.php from loading and still doesnt fix the issue with the cms.php